# Python excel cell type (Number, word, date, ...)

Tags: python, excel, types

I have a Python 3 code reading an excel sheet.

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('31s61934.xlsx')
```

I have to determine what is inside a specific cell. For example:

```
for row2 in range(5,9):
    cell2 = sheet.cell(row2, 4)
```

If cell2 is a number then I can go ahead and manipulate my data. If it is something else (like date, word, YES/No, N/A, ...) nothing should be done. How do I know is cell2 is a number (like 1.3333, -6.5555, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

use the type()

```
if type(cell2) == int or type(cell2) == float:
   print("Cell2 is a int")
   #Manipulate away!
```

I hope this is what you were asking.